# Why can I not concatenate two strings and assign them to a symbol?

Tags: ruby, string, concatenation, symbols

. . . as in this example:

```
helloworld.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting $end
:helloworld = "hello ".concat("world")
```

I thought if I use concat I'm modifying the string "hello " and adding "world" to it and then ultimately assigning the resulting string - "hello world" - to the :helloworld symbol on the left side of the equals sign. I thought that would be legal, just as if I had written:

```
:helloworld = "hello world"
```

oh, wait, that doesn't work either. (scratches head).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
:"hello world"
```

Answer (score 19):

Ruby symbols cannot have values assigned to them since they represent a canonical value. If you want to build a symbol from a string, you can use "hello ".concat("world").to_sym.

Comment: Thanks. How would I refer to that symbol later on, though? Do I have to always say: "hello ".concat("world").to_sym

Comment: There are a couple other options. :"hello world" is the most direct, but if the symbol is unknown until runtime, you could store it in a var: foo = "hello ".concat("world").to_sym.

Comment: You could even do something like `:"#{"plan_"}#{:date}"` which would result in `:plan_date`, or whatever, depending on the complexity of your requirement.

Answer (score 8):

symbols are confusing when coming from languages that don't have anything like them. You can't assign to symbols, that's not what they're for.

Here are a couple of examples that may help explain it.

```
5.times do |i|
  # a new string is created in each iteration of the loop
  puts "my string".object_id

  # there is only ever one symbol for each possible value
  # so a new object is not created during each iteration
  puts :my_symbol.object_id

  # this often makes a difference when you're using them for things like hash keys
  #some_method(:name => 'bob')
  #some_method('name' => 'bob')
end
```

The other big difference is that a symbol comparison is simply a pointer comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you're actually looking for is a constant? They can be dynamically generated, referred to later, and you get a warning if you try to reassign one.

```
>> HELLO_WORLD = "hello ".concat("world")
=> "hello world"
>> HELLO_WORLD = "foo"
(irb):3: warning: already initialized constant HELLO_WORLD
=> "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to a symbol but you can return a symbol which is a concatenation of other symbols, although you have to pass through strings as far as I know (I'd like to know if there is a better way).

Suppose you want to obtain the symbol `:myway` starting from the symbols `:my` and `:way` ;

```
(:my.to_s + :way.to_s).to_sym # return :myway
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah.  You can't assign to symbols.  Do you mean something like:

```
foo = { :helloworld => "hello ".concat("world") }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Symbol
  def + (to)
    return "#{self}#{to}".to_sym
  end
end
```

Comment: The question asked specifically on an explanation to why what the asker is trying does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@foo = 'world'
"hello #{@foo}".to_s.to_sym
```

output=>  :"hello world"

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function using default ruby string to symbol conversion.
Follow the example

```
def sum_of_two_sym(sym1, sym2)
    (sym1.to_s + sym2.to_s).to_sym
end

sum_of_two_sym(:hello, :world)
```

Result will show :helloworld

Here I just write a function, the name of function `sum_of_two_sym` I pass two parameter :hello and :world in two argument `sym1` and `sym2` then sym1 and sym2 convert to string and concatenate them and finally result convert string to symbol and return.